# When to load database in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a general question.

I have a website with a page showing many elements of my database.
And in this page I have a script where I'm loading these elements.

The the thing I want to know is it alright to load the database at the display of the page, knowing that everytime user will click and reload the page, my script will reload everything again from my database?

Is it a proper way to do it? Like creating an init.php at the first loading of the website, and storing my elements into a $_SESSION?

I don't know if I managed to explain my problem, so please ask me more informations if needed.

Comment: your problem is that you don't want to perform the SQL query every time a page is reloaded right ??

Comment: This is exactly my problem, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is pretty simple.

If you are sending a new request, it is wise to always start a new connection when needed and close it when its done.

But do not store the connection or any results in SESSION, as this can cause security issues. Creating a common script to start adn close a connection is the way to go.

Having said that look at [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) is it probably the thing you want.

Comment: I didn't knew for the SESSION. So I will go with what I was doing: start the connection, doing my stuff and closing it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not store the results in session.

If you don't want to perform the query every time the page loads, you can use several caching methods ( both client side and server side ) like.

[Memcache](http://memcached.org/.).

Comment: So the cach is the solution if we don't want to perform the query every time ! I am thanking you, and I will try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean connection do DB, I usually do some file, like "db_connect.php", where I connect to my DB and does any other stuff.

Then, everywhere I need to  something with it, I include it:

```
include_once "db_connect.php";
```

It's good to use **include_once** instead of **include**, because you can't include it twice accidently.

Don't store it in SESSION! It's better to include a file ;)

Comment: How are you planning to use the variable you obtained from "db_connect.php"? It's locked in that file's scope.

Comment: I understand this solution. But if I were to reload the page, the connection to DB and storage of the data will be repeated isn't it?

Comment: Yes, everything will be repeated. That's usual. If you don't want to load it everytime, cache it. Or give that some trigger

Truth: No, it's not locked. You can use it of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the session.

include_once is a good option to include the database connection file.

```
include_once "db_connect.php";
```

also, at the end of your file you may also want to include another file that does any database disconnect or cleanup.

```
include_once "db_disconnect.php";
```

If you know that every php page on your site you could also use the prepend functionalityy of php for your database connection, which would give every PHP page a database connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to store database stuff in the session. If however, that data is is no security risk, and you really really want to avoid database calls. You can go ahead and put them in the `$_SESSION` array, or even create cookies and store that data in. Just know that data is very insecure.

Also, lots of info stored in the SESSION stuff's your site memory. It's adviseable to clean out your $_SESSION and/or cookies.

Database calls are not a big deal, they take seconds, are safer;

Another way of storing data to avoid database calls is to cache files using output buffering.

Comment: I thought that database calls were the thing to avoid the most, but it seems that I overreacted against it.

Comment: yeah, they're not that bad. But if you wanted to avoid them and maybe get faster speeds, I'd consider caching content